# How are bhikkhus using social networking sites?

Tags: modern-world, teaching, media

I thought bhikkhus were to not to be involved with entertainment. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think their **intention** is to entertain but to to **teach**.Social Networking Sites can be used as a form for communication.Especially in this day and age.It's likened to them writing a letter or giving a dhamma talk.Since i don't attend any Buddhist monastery or retreats or groups,I have benefited from monks teaching the Dharma on Youtube or contacting a monastic via facebook when i had any questions etc.It is also a way for the monastic to keep in touch with the lay people.So intention plays a big role in why monastics use social networking sites.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that there are two types of using social networks in a monastery.

One is a collective use made by the whole community of monks and nuns, and this can be very wholesome, for giving teachings, reaching people and connecting with those who otherwise could not be in contact with the monastery.

The second one is the individual use made by individual monks and nuns who have access to Internet, and this is up to the single person and his practice on how to use it. In some monasteries  there are not strict limitations and monastics could use social networks as a lay person would do. If a monastic is truly dedicated to her practice, then she will use the social network in a wholesome way.

If one monk, for example, uses social networks for entertainment, he should recognize it, observe his mind, see that it is not beneficial and so he can make an effort to stop doing it. I think the same can be said also for lay people.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube/Facebook etc. are just tools... one doesn't watch "youtube", one watches a movie, a vídeoclip or a Dhamma talk for example.

Think in youtube as a simple channel of communication, if you use it right, watching, let's say, Dhamma talks or guided meditation, how can that be bad or breaking a precept? Same thing goes for facebook or blogs...

Answer (score 0):

Good householder,

Of course one living on alms wouldn't easy stay fault and remorseless if going into contract with common undertakings and use things which are actually not given to one (like as with posting here, if not personal invited by company). Yet less take the meaning "homeless" and depending on gifts seriously, even spread demands toward provider, as if they where customers. There are plenty of "monks" out there who even blame and criticize those who they "steal" from and motivate followers to do likewise.

How ever, if "taking in trust" is possible (knowing owner personal, he has expressed the offer of using personal or toward thega Sangha, knowing that he would be glad if using, still alive), one could make use.

The matter of entertainment shouldn't be one at all, of course, as such brings additional faults as well as communicating separated or exclusively with other gender or "eating" together with householder...

As for special circumstances, if depriving from the allowance for monks to receive alms from charities if just for 2, 3 times, it would be possible to "take temporary account" if perceiving a social network as charity (which is hardly found, sadly...).

As for laypeople, who, when wise, are after conductive deeds for themselves, good if organising given possibilities as if not it's natural to be only in contact with monks who don't care much on virtue, those not having left home. This should be what can be drawn from the topic for oneseft, aside of reflecting about the steady consume of not liberal intented offers. Hardly a layperson who would sacrifices proper to stay in contact, or? Nothing is for free but some bond to liberation, such as virtue and wise giving.

Do virtuous, act generous, be careful, keeping good and bad in mind, in regard of own actions.

Answer (score 0):

In regard of what's not given, like most, it's impossible in good ways. And of course people drift away if not giving condition at first place, will be just slaves of there unwillingness to give at first place. Slaves of huge IT-Brahmas (Maras), like here, corrupting the tradition of the Noble Ones for worldly gains.

As it isn't remorseless, faultless possible at all and would lead only to corruption, it's maybe an inspiring occasion that a generous developer gave a question and answer software toward the Sangha this days.

[Giving of a Question+Answer Software (Q&A) toward the Sangha](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=10639.msg28137#msg28137)

My person can only encourage those who have gained certain faith and love similar format to put efforts into development.

Of course, who ever feels good inspired, is given to implement such via given server and domain, and it's also garanted that open speech as well as non-harm, non-censure, will be secured by keeping precepts and virtue at first place.

As for communities and 'chat-like' talk, an [email based software](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=10211.0) was given for the Buddhaparisa: